# What does mean undefined offset issue?

Tags: php, search

I can't figure out where is mistake in this code and how to solve this error.

Error reported is:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bat/rd-search.php on line 53 that is this string of code:

```
$final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1];
```

the code is:

```
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $page_title); //getting page title
  if (preg_match("#\<body.*\>(.*)\<\/body\>#si", $contents, $body_content)) { //getting content only between <body></body> tags
    $clean_content = strip_tags($body_content[0]); //remove html tags
    $clean_content = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $clean_content); //remove duplicate whitespaces, carriage returns, tabs, etc

    $found = strpos_recursive(mb_strtolower($clean_content, 'UTF-8'), $search_term);

    $final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1]; 
    $final_result[$file_count]['file_name'][] = preg_replace("/^.{3}/", "\\1", $file);
  }

  for ($j = 0; $j < count($template_tokens); $j++) {
    if (preg_match("/\<meta\s+name=[\'|\"]" . $template_tokens[$j] . "[\'|\"]\s+content=[\'|\"](.*)[\'|\"]\>/", $contents, $res)) {
      $final_result[$file_count][$template_tokens[$j]] = $res[1];
    }
  }
```

Comment: It means that you try to reach the index '1' of an array, and this index doesn't exist. Try to check you preg_match, because it seems that it doesn't find any result

Comment: On line 52, just put `var_dump($page_title);` and tell us what the value is

Comment: In your case specifically it means the regex on the second line of your code did not find any matches.

Comment: @JustCarty and result is:     
      array(0) { } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "" [1]=> string(17) "Catalogo prodotti" } array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "" [1]=> string(17) "Catalogo prodotti" } array(2) { [0]=> string(49) "" [1]=> string(34) "Enable Remote Access to phpMyAdmin" } array(2) { [0]=> string(49) "" [1]=> string(34) "Increase the PHP File Upload Limit" } array(2) { [0]=> string(30) "" [1]=> string(15) "Lifting-Face Up" } array(0) { }

Comment: After this line `preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $page_title);`. Add another line which is the following: `$page_title = empty($page_title) ? [0 => '', 1 => ''] : $page_title;` This will just ensure that the $page_title variable has some value when you try and access it. The alternative is to change line 53 to `if (!empty($page_title) { $final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `preg_match` returns no matches.

You can resolve this by adding a line below such as the following:

```
preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $page_title); //getting page title
$page_title = empty($page_title) ? [0 => '', 1 => ''] : $page_title;
```

This will just create an array with 0 and 1 as indexes if `preg_match` failed to get any matches for a title.

The other alternative is to check the value of `$page_title` before trying to access it. This approach means that you will have to create a check each time you want to access this variable, whereas the first approach doesn't because the indexes have blank values.

```
if (!empty($page_title) {
    $final_result[$file_count]['page_title'][] = $page_title[1];
}
```

Comment: Great!! ;) your code works and all errors are disappeared!